# Ammeter and controlled sources in different subcircuits in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

Is it possible in LTspice to control a *current dependant current source* by the current readen by an ammeter (voltage source set to 0) in a different subcircuit? I've been struggling with this for a while, but I can't find a solution. Subcircuits are hierarchical blocks. CCCS and ammeter are placed in different subcircuits.

Comment: Can you add an example? I can't quite figure it out. You have a CCCS in one hierarchical schematic, and you need it as a function of a current through another subcircuit? Can you draw something to illustrate the concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible, with some abuse of notation, but should you really do it?

Like software functions, the whole point of subcircuits is to isolate their internals from things going on outside.

The correct way to do this would be to add the controlling and controlled signals to the pins of the subcircuits, and wire them up in the schematic.

This [obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/2044/) came to mind

[image]

The hover text for it is

> All I want is a secure system where it's easy to do anything I want. Is that so much to ask?

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to get these two subcircuits blocks to interact without necessarily having to wire them up in the schematic.

Comment: @AndreaRubino   Have you tried Pai's solution?

Comment: @AndreaRubino What you want cannot be done. Think of it: what if one of the subcircuits needs to be encrypted? How do you expose only that one part to the outside? How do you encrypt only the others?

Comment: Yes I tried but, as the ammeter and the CCCS, it works only if both the devices are placed in the same circuit.

Comment: I know this normally wouldn't be a best practice, but this is a very particular application of an acoustic circuit modeled with impedance analogy. I need two blocks to interact (possibly without wirings) in a controlled way with no possibility of errors.

Comment: It sounds like you need to open the subcircuits. Create a new subcircuit. Rename all the nodes in the previous two subcircuits, let's call them circuit A and circuit B, with A and B suffixes to avoid name clashes, then edit them all into one. Now they share a namespace, and the ammeter and CCCS will work. Resolve the new pinout, and any other clashes that weren't automatically fixed. Alternatively, modify each subcircuit with a new signal, and wire them at the schematic level. It sounds to me like the second is cleaner, more reliable, and less work.

Comment: I think I will go with the second option. I'm going to use one of the three subcircuits involved as a "connection" subcircuit to take all the connections between the others.

Comment: I could have solved it easily if there was the possibility of creating multiple symbols from the same subcircuit.

Comment: Could you please provide a link or citation for the graphic that you copied into your answer? We want to be sure to give credit to the original creator.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Thanks, good spot. I hadn't noticed that the image came up without any attribution. I copied the link 'for hotlinking/embedding' from Randall's site, which in my hurry I assumed would do the business. The alt-text doesn't work when linked like that either. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Sensing the current in the circuit and replicating the current value to be used in other  blocks in the schematics.

**How it works:**

`sen_res` is used as sensing resistor voltage drop across the resistor its voltage drop is `V=I*R`. R used is `1u`, gain of VCVS is choose as `1Meg`. Behavioral source is used for replication.

[image: Current Sensing]

Update:

Sub circuit version-hierarchy

[image: subcircuit]

[image: All]

Comment: As the ammeter with a CCCS it seems to work only if the behavioural source is placed in the same circuit of the sensing resistor.

Comment: @AndreaRubino I have updated the answer and it seems working fine

Comment: Thank you Pai. I apologize if I didn't make myself clear: sensing circuit and behavioural source must be in two different subcircuits.

Comment: @AndreaRubino Even that is possible Please attach a screen shot of the problem in this community so that we can guide you better

Comment: @AndreaRubino Hope this answer helped please upvote and tick it if it worked for you

Comment: Hi Pai, I've not enough reputation yet to vote :-(